# Query multiple collections with expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have some IQueryable collections provided by EF Core and I want to build a dynamic query for them using System.Linq.Expressions for Entity to translate it into SQL.

```
IQueryable<ADP> collection1 = _context.Adps;
IQueryable<VHStr> collection2 = _context.VHStrParams;

var q = (from ADP a in collection1
        where collection2.Any(p => p.Value.Contains("I") && p.Entid == a.Id)
        select a);

var l = q.ToList();
```

This works properly and Entity produces correct SQL.

The question is - how can I build such query using Expressions? I just can't figure out how can I access another collection in the expressions built for elements of the first one...

EDIT: In case someone will find it, the solution is:

```
        IQueryable<ADP> collection1 = _context.Adps;
        IQueryable<VHStr> collection2 = _context.VHStrParams;


        var q = (from ADP a in collection1
                 where collection2.Any(p => p.Value.Contains("I") && p.Entid == a.Id)
                 select a);

        var paramExpA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ADP), "a");
        var paramExpV = Expression.Parameter(typeof(VHStr), "v");

        var entIdExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExpV, "Entid");
        var adpIdExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExpA, "Id");
        var convertedAdpIdExp = Expression.Convert(adpIdExp, typeof(long?));

        var valueExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(paramExpV, "Value");
        var containsStringMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof(string)});
        var constValueExp = Expression.Constant("I", typeof(string));
        var containsExp = Expression.Call(valueExp, containsStringMethod, constValueExp);

        var equalIdsExp = Expression.Equal(entIdExp, convertedAdpIdExp);
        var andExp = Expression.AndAlso(containsExp, equalIdsExp);

        var lambda1 = Expression.Lambda<Func<VHStr, bool>>(andExp, paramExpV);
        var vhstrAnyMethod =
            typeof(Queryable)
                .GetTypeInfo()
                .GetMethods()
                .First(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2)
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(VHStr));

        var collection2ConstExpr = Expression.Constant(collection2);
        var anyCallExp = Expression.Call(vhstrAnyMethod, collection2ConstExpr, lambda1);

        var collection1ConstExpr = Expression.Constant(collection1);
        var lambda2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<ADP, bool>>(anyCallExp, paramExpA);

        var whereExp = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { typeof(ADP) },
            collection1ConstExpr,
            lambda2);

        var lambda3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<ADP>>>(whereExp);
        var resultFunc = lambda3.Compile();
        var resultQuerable = resultFunc();

        var resultList = resultQuerable.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just can't figure out how can I access another collection in the expressions built for elements of the first one...

Well, the compile time query uses a closure class to pass external variables to the query. You can do the same when building expression tree manually, but there is no need to do that because you can simply use [`Expression.Constant`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.constant(v=vs.110).aspx) method to turn a variable into expression:

```
var collection2expr = Expression.Constant(collection2);
var anyParam = Expression.Parameter(collection2.ElementType, "p");
var anyPredicate = Expression.Lambda(
    dynamically_built_predicate_body, // p.Value.Contains("I") && p.Entid == a.Id
    anyParam);
var anyCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable), "Any", new Type[] { anyParam.Type },
    collection2Expr, Expression.Quote(anyPredicate));
// etc...
```

Comment: The point is - how exactly can i add the condition "p.Entid == a.Id" to the `dynamically_built_predicate_body` as that are fields from different entities?

Comment: I think it's obvious. `p` is the `anyParam` from the above snippet. `a` will be another `ParameterExpression` that you will create (e.g. `var a = Expression.Parameter(collection1.ElementType, "a");` and will be used to produce the predicate for `Where` call using the `anyCall` expression as body. You should be able to generate the concrete conditions from there. For `p.Entid == a.id` it would be `Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(anyParam, "Entid"), Expression.PropertyOrField(a, "id"))` etc.

Comment: Thanks, the Expression.Constant was a point to the right direction.